# Subscribing to characteristics using handles using Noble/Node

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy

In order to communicate with a device I'm now using `peripheral.discoverServices` and `peripheral.discoverCharacteristics` to discover all available characteristics, and I match those to a list of known characteristics UUIDs (as per [the pizza example in the Noble repository](https://github.com/noble/noble/tree/master/examples/pizza)).

This means I connect to my device, discover and match the characteristics, write and read from the ones I need (including subscribing to a characteristic that needs some time to return a response, preventing the need for polling).

This all works as expected. But as I need to poll 30+ different devices at regular intervals it feels a bit odd to have to go through the discovering part every time and for every device.

In an attempt to skip the discovering and speed up the process I tried using the characteristics' handles (which are the same for all devices).
They allow me to communicate straight after connecting to the device using `peripheral.readHandle(...)` and `peripheral.writeHandle(...)`. instead of having to go through discovering first. But it seems this way only allows reading and writing, not subscribing, which I really prefer above polling.

So the question is; is there a way to subscribe to a characteristic through its handle, or to get a handle's characteristic directly so I can subscribe to it, instead of having to go through discovering every time?